# Why was Lot afraid and ran to hill places?

Tags: genesis, lot

"Now Lot went up out of Zoar and settled in the hills with his two daughters, for he was afraid to stay in Zoar; so he lived in a cave with his two daughters."

Genesis 19:30 NRSV
https://bible.com/bible/2016/gen.19.30.NRSV

If God had given him that land, and God did not destroy Zoar. Why Lot has to run from that city and go to mountain ?
Is there any cultural background that can help me understand this passage in better way.
Moreover, what was he afraid about ?

Comment: Where does it say God gave Lot the land?

Comment: Hi @Dave, I am just trying to understand why LOT was afraid. _"21He said to him, “Very well, I grant you this favor too, and will not overthrow the city of which you have spoken."_ it clearly tells God had favored him and God saved him.

Comment: Don’t get me wrong, you have a fair question. One that is well worth considering. But the promise of ‘land’ was to Abraham and his descendants.- not relatives. In fact, he was told not to bring relatives’ (Lot) - Nevertheless, Lot’s ‘favor’ came as a result of being under Abraham’s covenant, and for no other reason. Lot didn’t know ‘this God’, hence the unsureness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Genesis 19:23 By the time Lot reached Zoar, the sun had risen over the land. 24Then the Lord **rained down burning sulfur** on Sodom and Gomorrah—from the Lord out of the heavens. 25Thus he overthrew those cities and the entire plain, destroying all those living in the cities—and also the vegetation in the land. 26But Lot’s wife looked back, and she became **a pillar of salt**.

Basically, Lot was still in a state of shock thinking about what had just happened. We are reading the happenings like watching TV. Lot was there in person in the midst. He panicked and wanted to play it more safe.

Ellicott gives some more reasons, https://biblehub.com/genesis/19-30.htm

> (30) He feared to dwell in Zoar.--Though this little place had been granted him for an asylum, yet, terrified at the sight of the smoking valley, and remembering that he had been originally commanded to go to the mountains, he summons up his courage and proceeds thither. The limestone regions of Palestine are full of caverns; and the patriarch, whose wealth had been so great that he and Abraham could not dwell together, is now content to seek in one of these caverns a miserable home.

Lot was scared. Very few people wouldn't be.

> Genesis 19:15 With the coming of dawn, the angels urged Lot, saying, “Hurry! Take your wife and your two daughters who are here, or you will be swept away when the city is punished.”
>
> 16When he **hesitated**, the men grasped his hand and the hands of his wife and of his two daughters and led them safely out of the city, for the Lord was merciful to them. 17As soon as they had brought them out, one of them said, “Flee for your lives! Don’t look back, and don’t stop anywhere in the plain! **Flee to the mountains** or you will be swept away!”

Put yourself in his shoes. You may do the same just in case of whatever. The people of Zoar may blame you and your daughters, the foreigner, for the disaster: Why are you the only ones who have survived Sodom and Gomorrah?

Comment: Thanks @Tony, I am beginning to see it now, the struggle of fear/doubt and faith in God. Thanks for a detailed explanation for the passage to understand it better. May I ask one more question, _could it be that there were still people in ZOAR and LOT was afraid of those people and that's why he decided to play safe and went to the hills as he was first commanded to do that_ - not sure if there is any historical evidence for that ?

Comment: Yes, I think so.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Lot left Zoar to the Hills because:
i. that is where the Angel originally instructed him to go - Genesis 19:17c - Flee . . .
ii. It was by permissive will he went to Zoar because Zoar was closer to him than the mountain and was too scared to run that far - Genesis 19:19c - he was afraid to die, seeing that the devastating effects of the judgement might overtake him

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The fleeing family expected Zoar to be a reprieve where they could end their flight. But as they were arriving in Zoar, four unexpected things happened which left them reeling and urgently wanting to move on.

- Firstly, the angels, with their mission now accomplished, departed,
  leaving the family alone. These angels had been central to the
  family’s survival, having blinded the depots, having collected the
  family, having guided them when they were overwhelmed by the
  confusion, and having taken them by the hand to flee from the
  mayhem—truly lifesavers—now gone.
- Secondly, upon their arrival, God rained down fire on the two
  northern cities behind them, Sodom and Gomorrah. Though they had
  escaped Sodom in time, there were now fires both ahead of them (Admah
  and Zeboiim), as well as behind them (Sodom and Gomorrah). Of this,
  Josephus says, "Now he and his daughters fled to a certain small
  place [Zoar], encompassed with the fire, and settled in it."
- Thirdly, as the cities and plains behind them went up in flames,
  Lot's wife looked back and became a pillar of salt. Josephus notes
  the nature of this disobedience: "Lot's wife continually turning back
  to view the city as she went from it, and being too nicely
  inquisitive what would become of it, although God had forbidden her
  so to do, was changed into a pillar of salt."
- Fourthly, now in desperate need of physical and emotional support,
  they realized that the city of Zoar was abandoned, empty of
  inhabitants. Josephus says of Lot's time there. "There it was that he
  lived a miserable life, on account of his having no company, and his
  want of provisions." See also Genesis 19:31.

At this point, Lot’s family was in Zoar between two apocalyptic fires, with two cities behind them and two cities ahead of them (and the plains) all in flames. With the angels’ departure, and now his wife’s demise, and finding the Zoar abandoned—where they had anticipated refuge—Lot suddenly changed his mind: despite the risk of getting to the mountains, they would flee from Zoar like its other inhabitants already had, lest this city is destroyed like the former four.

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803). I also recommend going through the [Help Center](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help)'s sections on both asking and answering questions.

Answer (score -1):

Lot and his remaining family were the only survivors and, the town's people put a lot of pressure on them in explaining what happened and why and who brought "fire and brimstone." Once Lot revealed what truly happened he had to deal with non-believers and that social pressure caused Lot fear.

Abram and Sarai went through worrying about societal pressure causing Abram to deny Sarai being called his wife, making her promise she would just say she was his sister. Abram had fear entering into a hostile land known as Egypt. God didn't punish Abram from not trusting Him. Lot ran because of that same type of fear.

So Lot was not running because of punishment/guilt for not trusting in God. Trust is a broad definition for a lot of people. Lot was scared they were going to blamed for the possibility of relatives of Zoarians who lived in Sodom. Lot didn't run because he got depressed due to making the wrong decision of running to Zoar.

Comment: Thanks for the response, however, you'll need to provide contextual or grammatical evidence for your answers in the future. You have provided some explanations why Lot was afraid, you should now just tie them to the scripture themselves.